# SQLAlchemy: Hybrid expression with relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two Flask-SQLAlchemy models with a simple one-to-many relationship, like the minimal example below:

```
class School(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(30))
    address = db.Column(db.String(30))

class Teacher(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(30))
    id_school = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(School.id))

    school = relationship('School', backref='teachers')
```

Then I add an hybrid property to teacher that uses the relationship, like so:

```
@hybrid_property
def school_name(self):
    return self.school.name
```

And that property works just fine when I use it as `teacher_instance.school_name`. However, I'd also like to make queries like `Teacher.query.filter(Teacher.school_name == 'x')`, but that gives me an error:

```
`AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 
'Comparator' object has an attribute 'school_name'`.
```

Following SQLAlchemy documentation, I added a simple hybrid expression, like the following:

```
@school_name.expression
def school_name(cls):
    return School.name
```

However, when I try the same query again, it generates an SQL query without the join clause, so I get all available rows in School, not only those matching the foreign key in Teacher.

From SQLAlchemy documentation I realized that the expression expects a context where the join is already present, so I tried the query again as:

`Teacher.query.join(School).filter(Teacher.school_name == 'x')`

And that actually works, but it defeats the purpose of trying to get the syntactic sugar in there in the first place if I need knowledge of the School model to get that. I expect there's a way to get that join in the expression, but I couldn't find it anywhere. The documentation has an example with the expression returning a subquery built directly with the `select()`, but even that didn't work for me.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

After Eevee's answer below, I used the association proxy as suggested and it works, but I also got curious with the comment that it should work with the `select()` subquery and tried to figure out what I did wrong. My original attempt was:

```
@school_name.expression
def school_name(cls):
    return select(School.name).where(cls.id_school == School.id).as_scalar()
```

And it turns out that was giving me an error because I had missed the list in select(). The code below works fine:

```
@school_name.expression
def school_name(cls):
    return select([School.name]).where(cls.id_school == School.id).as_scalar()
```

Comment: I wonder how is it possible to implement this but on the [parent side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68678357/sqlalchemy-hybrid-expression-with-relationship-on-parent).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A much simpler approach for a simple case like this is an [association proxy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html):

```
class Teacher(db.Model):
    school_name = associationproxy('school', 'name')
```

This supports querying (at least with `==`) automatically.

I'm curious how the hybrid `select()` example didn't work for you, since that's the easiest way to fix this within a hybrid.  And for the sake of completion, you could also use a [transformer](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#building-transformers) to amend the query directly rather than subquerying.

Comment: That's ridiculously simple. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You were right about the `select()`. My mistake. I added an update to the question detailing it.

Comment: Hey, can you elaborate on how it supports querying? I tried to find the syntax online but failed to find meaningful results.

Comment: @Curtwagner1984 it should work the same way as any other column query — `Teacher.school_name == "Bob Dylan Elementary"`

Comment: @Eevee I see. I meant how can you tell the proxy only to check in a subset of entries. For example, if a `Teacher` has multiple `nicknames` and only one of those nicknames is his real name, and the other are just nicknames. So `nicknames` has two fields, `name` and `is_primary`. And now I want Teacher.name to give me the equivalent of `SELECT nickname.name from nicknames join teacher on nicknames.teacher_id = teacher.id where nickname.is_primary = true limit 1`