# SQLAlchemy hybrid expression concat issue

Tags: python, mysql, properties, sqlalchemy, hybrid

Here is the following issue that I'm trying to resolve for 2 days, but without success:

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Parent'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'Schema', 'extend_existing': True}

    Id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    Name = Column(String(255))


class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Child'
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint('ParentId', 'Name'),
                      {'schema': 'Schema', 'extend_existing': True})

    Id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    ParentId = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Schema.Parent.Id'))
    Name = Column(String(255))

    parent = relationship('Parent', uselist=False, viewonly=True,
                               backref='children')

    @hybrid_property
    def ChildResourceId(self):
        return self.parent.Name + '-' + self.Name

    @ChildResourceId.expression
    def ChildResourceId(cls):
        # This is the main issue:
        # Which is the proper expression
        # for this hybrid property

child = session.query(Child).filter_by(ChildResourceId='parent_name1-child_name1').one()
# Returns child with Id: 1
child = session.query(Child).filter_by(ChildResourceId='parent_name2-child_name1').one()
# Also returns child with Id: 1
```

The idea here is to use the combination of parent.Name and the child.Name as search criteria.
And I want to do it with the hybrid functionality instead with explicit join query or additional selects.

I tried multiple expressions with the concat function or simple cls expression like:

```
return cls.parent.Name + '-' + cls.Name
```

But those doesn't work in my case, because as you can see in the code snippet - the queries perform lookup only by child.Name and ignores the parent.Name.

Comment: Try using a subquery with select() in your expression method. Take a look at the update here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780178/sqlalchemy-hybrid-expression-with-relationship

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the "select" expression itself is not enough and "where" clause is required. "label" will return scalar selectable (subquery) with additional tagging for the specific sql expression.

This is one possible solution:

```
@ChildResourceId.expression
def ChildResourceId(cls):
    return select([Parent.Name + '-' + cls.Name]).\
        where(Parent.Id == cls.ParentId).label('resource_id')
```