# Use hybridattribute on relationship in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to get the following contrived example to work:

```
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = "persons"
    __table_args__ = {"mysql_charset": "utf8mb4"}

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50), index=True, unique=True)
    birthday = Column(Boolean, default=False)

    @hybrid_property
    def is_birthday_person(self):
        return self.birthday == True

class Party(Base):
    __tablename__ = "parties"
    __table_args__ = {"mysql_charset": "utf8mb4"}

    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    one_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("persons.id"))
    two_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("persons.id"))

    one_person = relationship("Person", foreign_keys=[one_id])
    two_person = relationship("Person", foreign_keys=[two_id])
    sunshine = Column(Boolean, default=False)

    @hybrid_property
    def everyones_birthday_in_sunshine(self):
        return self.one_person.is_birthday_person and self.two_person.is_birthday_person and self.sunshine
```

What I am trying to achieve is to filter all parties and only return parties where both persons celebrate their birthday and the sun is shining when I run the following query:

`session.Query(Party).filter(Party.everyones_birthday_in_sunshine).all()`

The error I am getting is:

`AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Party.one_person has an attribute 'is_birthday_person'`

When I change `everyones_birthday_in_sunshine` to:
`return self.sunshine == True`

It works and return all parties where the sun in shining when I run:

`session.Query(Party).filter(Party.everyones_birthday_in_sunshine).all()`

So the problem lies in the relationship between Party and Person, but I can't figure out how to get it to work.

Edit:
When I try to print properties from the person instance in Party: `everyones_birthday_in_sunshine` eg: `one_person.name` it just prints out `Party.one_person`. Definitly a relationship issue I guess.

Comment: I think you should look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780178/sqlalchemy-hybrid-expression-with-relationship

Comment: I've seen that question. That makes use of the backref relationship type. I don't know if that's the problem, but seeing as I have two different relationships to the same Person class I can't use backref as far as I know.