# SQLAlchemy - Column as the result of a sub query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two tables managed by SQLAlchemy, like this:

```
class Contact(db.Model):
    __tablename__      = 'contacts'

    id                  = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    name                = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True, default=None)
    email               = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)

    last_posted_message = db.SubQuery('SELECT created FROM messages WHERE contact_id = {current_alias}.id ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1')


class Message(db.Model):
    __tablename__      = 'messages'

    id                  = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    message             = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    created             = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)

    contact_id          = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('contacts.id'))
```

As you might have guessed, I'm trying to implement the `last_posted_message`, asking SQLAlchemy to do a subquery for that specific column. This would be easily possible in a SQL query, like this:

```
'SELECT c.id, c.name, c.email, (SELECT created FROM messages WHERE contact_id = c.id ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1) AS last_posted_message FROM contacts c'
```

So I'm hoping it's something that can be implemented via SQLAlchemy, without many troubles.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLAlchemy: Hybrid expression with relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780178/sqlalchemy-hybrid-expression-with-relationship)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm not sure because I need to define some ordering on the sub query, and from the look of the hybrid expression, this is not possible.