# SQLAlchemy: Hybrid expression with relationship (on parent)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Similar to question [SQLAlchemy: Hybrid expression with relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780178/sqlalchemy-hybrid-expression-with-relationship) but I would like to know what is the best method to implement hybrid expresions on the parent. The adapted example:

```py
class School(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(30))
    address = db.Column(db.String(30))
    teachers = relationship('Teacher', back_populates='school')
    

class Teacher(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(30))
    id_school = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(School.id))
    school = relationship('School', back_populates='teachers')
```

Then I add an hybrid property to school that uses the relationship, like so:

```py
@hybrid_property
def n_teachers(self):
    return len(self.teachers)
```

Now the key of the question is what is the best way to provide this property into query filters like `School.query.filter(School.n_teachers >= 10)` (`association_proxy`, `@<hybird_property>.expression`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

```py
from sqlalchemy import select, func

    @n_teachers.expression
    def n_teachers(self):
        return select([func.count(Teacher.id)]).where(Teacher.id_school == self.id).as_scalar()
```